# Finding the correct actions url

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, controller

struggling to decipher how to link a plugins controller to an action route. The docs say to use "https://pluginfactory.io/" to scaffold one, but what it generates is a different structure to what the documentation say to use.

I've got a plugin called `Gated Content` sitting inside: `plugins/gated-content`

I've got a controller named and located at:

```
plugins/gated-content/src/controllers/GatedContent_DataCaptureController.php
```

with the class name of of `GatedContent_DataCaptureController`

I've just got an `actionIndex` method which var dumps and exits.

Which would suggest (according to the docs) that the URL to access this should be:

```
https://craftcms.localhost/index.php?p=actions/gatedContent/dataCapture/index
```

But it just throws a 404.

Inside of the `.craftplugin` file I've also added `"controllerName":"GatedContent_DataCaptureController` incase, but doesn't seem to make a difference.

What is the correct pattern to use for each of these?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
In the first version of the answer I forgot the `/admin` part of all the example URLs. Added now.

**TL;DR version:**

To get to the point first before explaining more in-depth: You need to convert the names from camelCase (with capitalisation in the name) to kebab-case (with dashes instead). I would suggest renaming your controller to simply `DataCaptureController`, since it's within the Gated Content plugin anyways, and you should be able to use:

```
https://craftcms.localhost/admin/gated-content/data-capture/index
```

**Full answer:**

So, the structure is basically `plugin-name/controller-name/method-name`, all in kebab case, meaning that what is `someName` should be `some-name`, as not all servers are case sensitive (althouth URLs technically are, if I'm correct). Also, the `Controller` and `action` parts of the class/method name is implied, as you've already correctly done, but as far as I know, not adding the plugin name to the front of your controller (I have not checked this specifically).

So in your case it should be something like this:

```
https://craftcms.localhost/admin/index.php?p=actions/gated-content/gated-content_data-capture/index
```

I am honestly not quite sure how underscores are treated in kebab-case, so it could be that this is the correct form:

```
https://craftcms.localhost/admin/index.php?p=actions/gated-content/gated-content-data-capture/index
```

Also, you should be able to use the url like this:

```
https://craftcms.localhost/admin/gated-content/gated-content-data-capture/index
```

(Or, if you really prefer for some reason, with `/actions` in the URL:)

```
https://craftcms.localhost/admin/actions/gated-content/gated-content-data-capture/index
```